# Ajax request to Django returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: django, ajax

I`m pretty new in Django and I`m trying to collect data with Ajax.
Additionally, I would like to add I`m trying to make and edit quiz app from tutorial(so I`m doing it by tutorial, not from the scratch.

[After clicked button I got an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRGaj.png)

```
console.log('hello world quiz')
const url = window.location.href
console.log(url)

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `${url}data`,
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function(error){
    console.log(error)
    }
})
```

I see that path is wrong, it should be: http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/, not http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/data. But changing from:

```
url: `${url}data`,
```

to:

```
url: `${url}`,
```

[not collecting information about amount of arrays etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt54S.png)

I have also error from terminal:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ad/Documents/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 34, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/home/ad/Documents/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 115, in _get_response
> response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/ad/Documents/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 113, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/ad/Documents/test01/src/quizes/views.py", line 20, in
> quiz_data_view
> for q in quiz.get_questions():   File "/home/ad/Documents/test01/src/quizes/models.py", line 22, in
> get_questions
> return self.question_set.all[:self.number_of_questions] TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

But really no idea what could I change in **quizes/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


DIFF_CHOICES = (
    ('easy', 'easy'),
    ('medium', 'medium'),
    ('hard', 'hard'),
)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    number_of_questions = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.IntegerField(help_text="duration of the quiz in minutes")
    required_score_to_pass = models.IntegerField(help_text="required score in %")
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=DIFF_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}-{self.topic}"

    def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all[:self.number_of_questions]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ='Quizes'
```

or **quizes/views.py:**

```
from typing import Text
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Quiz
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.http import JsonResponse
# Create your views here.

class QuizListView(ListView):
    model = Quiz 
    template_name = 'quizes/main.html'

def quiz_view(request, pk):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'quizes/quiz.html', {'obj': quiz})
    

def quiz_data_view(request, pk):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
    questions = []
    for q in quiz.get_questions():
        answers = []
        for a in q.get_answers():
            answers.append(a.text)
        questions.append({str(q): answers})
    return JsonResponse({
        'data': questions,
        'time': quiz.time,
    })
```

Can you help me with some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all[:self.number_of_questions]
```

should be:

```
def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all()[:self.number_of_questions]
```

And it works.